# Multiple "k8s-ha-app1-jobmanager" configmaps on every Flink job run

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, high-availability

I have a Flink **session** cluster on top of Kubernetes and recently I switched from the ZK based HA to Kubernetes HA.

Reading through
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-144%3A+Native+Kubernetes+HA+for+Flink#FLIP144:NativeKubernetesHAforFlink-LeaderElection

I can observe on the Flink namespace the configmaps for each resource as described in the docs above:

```
k8s-ha-app1-00000000000000000000000000000000-jobmanager   2      4m35s  
k8s-ha-app1-dispatcher                                    2      4m38s  
k8s-ha-app1-resourcemanager                               2      4m38s  
k8s-ha-app1-restserver                                    2      4m38s
```

However, I don't see a single configmap for the "jobmanager" resource. I see as many, as jobs are run accross the day. This can be a high number, so over days, it implies a **huge surge of configmaps** in the cluster namespace.

The different HA configmaps for the jobmanager seem to differ both in the

> "address":
> "akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/jobmanager_XXX"

(where XXX is increasing)
and the "sessionId" value.

Can someone please explain to me on what basis these "jobmanager" resources are created?
At the beginning I thought there might be scheduled cleanup round, but I read at the docs that the HA configmaps are stripped from owner and not deleted.
Did I miss to set something so that all the jobs are run against the same session, or some way that I can get these k8s-ha-app1-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-jobmanager cleaned up after the job runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Flink works internally is that the `Dispatcher` creates for every submitted job a dedicated `JobMaster` component. This component needs a leader election and for this purpose it creates a `k8s-ha-app1-<JOB_ID>-jobmanager` config map. This is the reason why you see multiple `xyz-jobmanager` ConfigMaps being created.

The reason why these ConfigMaps are not cleaned up is that this currently happens only when the whole cluster is shut down. This is a limitation and the Flink community has created [FLINK-20695](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20695) in order to fix it. The idea is that the `JobMaster` related ConfigMaps can be deleted after the job has reached a terminal state.

A bit related is another limitation which hampers the proper clean up in case of a session cluster. If the cluster is shut down with a SIGTERM signal then it is currently not guaranteed that all resources are cleaned up. See [FLINK-21008](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-21008) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Till, that was the useful specific details I needed to fill the gaps